# Associate global value with signal

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads

My intention is to let send() omit signal when the global counter is odd, and broadcast when even. Then there are 2 recv() thread, waiting for signal. In case of signal, only one of the recv() thread can receive it; in case of broadcast, both may receive it.

But my result shows me that both recv() received the same odd number, which should not happen.

Is the global counter and the signal tightly coupled in my code?

**edit:**

I think I get answer to this question. After a recv() thread receives signal, it will try to lock the mutex associated with the condition variable again, but it may need to wait because the mutex may have already been locked by other thread. During the waiting period, the global count may be changed, so the global count it finally prints is different from the one when it received signal.

Also, in my code, even send() send broadcast, multiples recv() threads actually can not handle the signal concurrently, because they are still exclusive to each other because they share the same mutex

**end of edit**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int n = 0;
int count = 0;

void* recv(void *name)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        // wait for signal
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        count++;

        if(count > 10)
        {
            printf("number %d terminate %s\n", n, (char*)name);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s gets number:%d\n", (char*)name, n);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        if(count > 10)
        {
            return (NULL);
        }
    }
}

void* send(void *ptr)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        n++;
        //  odd: signal
        // even: broadcast
        if(n%2)
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        else
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    pthread_t t1, t2, t3;

    char *name1 = "t1";
    char *name2 = "t2";

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, recv, (void *) name1);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, recv, (void *) name2);
    pthread_create(&t3, NULL, send, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
        pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    pthread_cancel(t3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output, note the first 2 lines:

```
t2 gets number:12493
t1 gets number:12493
t1 gets number:12534
t2 gets number:12534
t1 gets number:12623
t1 gets number:12624
t2 gets number:12666
t1 gets number:12666
t2 gets number:12713
t1 gets number:12713
number 12770 terminate t2
number 12998 terminate t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a broadcast wakeup, there is no guarantee that the threads will be scheduled as:

```
t1
t2
t3
```

or

```
t2
t1
t3
```

It is entirely possible that you get:

```
t1
t3
t2
```

...in which t3 increments `n` to an odd value and wakes up t1, and t2 and t1 then both print that odd number.

If you want to closely interlock execution like this you will need to introduce more synchronisation.

Comment: Even with a schedule of t3 (the wakeup) - t1 - t2 - t3 it is entirely possible to get wrong results here. The central issue with the code is that t1 and t2 are printing the values of n after they received the signal and got the mutex, not at the time the signal was sent. t3 will have incremented n many times during its first time slice.

Comment: @thiton: Yes, it depends on the scheduling algorithm as to what you actually get.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this result is because you are incrementing your global `n` variable in `send()`. If you incremented it in `recv()` instead you would see a different result. The reason is that each thread receives the broadcast or signal respectively, one after the other, and prints the result, but only one send occurs for each recv to happen for that send.

If you want to see it count up on a per thread basis, you should increment a variable inside the lock in `recv()`

By the way, these are names of other c functions. You should probably pick other ones.

Answer (score 0):

The signal/broadcast function works asynchronously: send() does not relinquish control at the moment when it signals, but rather cycles through its loop until its timeslice is up. Both t1 and t2 were waken up plenty of times during the timeslice of send(), so both print values.